# Galeria de imágenes traídas desde una base de datos con diferentes tamaños

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap

Quisiera lograr una galería de imágenes traídas desde una base de datos utilizando Bootstrap pero asignarle clases distintas para que no se vea como la típica galería, por ejemplo, que **una imagen cuente con la clase col-lg-4, la segunda col-lg-2**, etc, no sé si me explico. Hasta ahora he logrado traerlas pero se les aplica la misma clase a todas ya que lo hago de la siguiente manera:

```
function showGallery() {
    global $conexion;
    $pic_sql = "SELECT id, url_image FROM pictures WHERE status = 'A'";    
    if ($pics_query = mysqli_query($conexion, $pic_sql)) {
        $pics_rs = mysqli_fetch_assoc($pics_query);
    }
    do {
        ?>
        <div class='container-img col-lg-4'>
            <img src="img/<?php echo $pics_rs['url_image'] ?>" id="myImg-<?php echo $pics_rs['id'] ?>" name="<?php echo $pics_rs['id'] ?>" class="col-lg-12 myImg">        
        </div>
        <?php
    } while ($pics_rs = mysqli_fetch_assoc($pics_query));
}
?>
```

He retomado ésto después de tiempo y ya ni recuerdo, ya he buscado en Internet pero todo lo que voy encontrando es como hacer una en donde todas tienen el mismo tamaño.

Lo único que se me ocurre por ahora sería añadirle un campo adicional con el número que quiero que ocupe y hacer un if en donde pregunte si ese campo es igual a 'x' número entonces que aplique tal estilo.

Comment: Hola, no creo que tu problema se encuentre en el código php, ¿podrías remplazarlo por el código generado por php?

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es generar una clase propia y no asignar las de Bootstrap al Objeto Img, donde a la clase propia asignes el ancho y alto que necesitas para tu carrusel, esto sería lo más recomendable ya que si asignas las clases de Bootstrap te va a generar contenido Responsivo que va a respetar las dimensiones de la imagen, por lo tanto se van a ver de forma distinta cada una de ellas.